# Source code of a String Class in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I can't figure out what this lines do:

```
this.value = "".value;
```

and

```
int len2 = anotherString.value.length;
```

There is an array called "values" in the beginning of the class. It's something like String.Array (Array of chars).

How does it work?

Comment: Can you clarify which part you don't understand?  You're correct that `value` is `private final char value[];`, so what's the issue?

Comment: I see no particular reason to think so, @JustinKSU.

Comment: Without context it's hard for us to understand what these lines do. Tell us what you don't understand specifically and provide more of the surrounding code.

Comment: Check out the comments of the source file.

Comment: @JanHabjan - See the tags and the question/content.

Comment: It's the source code of the String class

Comment: Sorry, I thought it's a mistake.

Comment: `""` is a `String` literal.  It has all the fields and methods of any other `String`.  The implementation of `String` can access all `String` fields and methods, including private ones, including of different `String` instances.

Comment: @Rohan - This code, for example: public String() {
        this.value = "".value;
    }

Answer (score 3):

Since the *value* field contains the characters for the *String* instance, what you see is the constructor using the *value* field of the (usually) interned empty string constant.

This way, an empty string created with the empty constructor will all use the same instance of the array. *String*s are immutable, so they can and usually do, share the underlying *char* array to save on memory usage.

Comment: It seems like i get it, but i can't do it in code myself. It just does'n work, although code is the same that in String class

Comment: You can't access the value field in your own code because it's a private field of the String class. Otherwise strings would be able to change beneath your feet at any time and that would be a bad thing™

Comment: @IlyaFalko That is probably because you are trying to access the `value` field of a `String` aren't you? That field is **private**. So only the class itself (`String`) is allowed to access and manipulate this field. Here is the [official overview](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) of access modifiers. However you can get a copy of that `value` field by using the `String#toCharArray` method. But as said, it's only a clone, so it will not be tied to any string.